# Send a gRPC to multiple instances of the same microservice in NestJS

Tags: node.js, nestjs, grpc

I have a microservice A that needs to send a gRPC to multiple instances of microservice B.

What I want to achieve is similar to the publish/subscribe pattern of socket.io where microservice A would publish a message of a certain type to which all the instances of microservice B are subscribed.

In this case tho the protocol used must be gRPC.

I know how to achieve this with only one instance of microservice B.

In such case I would declare this in the module of microservice A that must send a gRPC to microservice B:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ClientsModule.register([
      {
        name: MICROSERVICEB_SERVICE_NAME,
        transport: Transport.GRPC,
        options: {
          url: 'microservice B url',
          package: MICROSERVICEB_PACKAGE_NAME,
          protoPath: 'location of microservice B proto file',
        },
      },
    ]),
  ],
  controllers: [MICROSERVICEAController],
  providers: [MICROSERVICEAService],
})
```

What I want to achieve tho is that I'm able to declare multiple urls, each one corresponding to a different instance of microservice B and make microservice A send the gRPC to all the instances of B at the same time.